# Htaccess url rewrite help

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]



RewriteRule ^home.html$ index__.php [L]
RewriteRule ^prodotti.html$ prodotti.php [L]
RewriteRule ^azienda.html$ azienda.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news.html$ news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^outlet.html$ outlet.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contatti.html$ contatti.php [L]

RewriteRule ^news-(.*).html$ news.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^arr.html$ prodotti-cat.php?cat=a [L]
RewriteRule ^sed.html$ prodotti-cat.php?cat=s [L]
RewriteRule ^par.html$ prodotti-cat.php?cat=p [L]
RewriteRule ^cont.html$ prodotti-cat.php?cat=c [L]
RewriteRule ^comp.html$ prodotti-cat.php?cat=co [L]

RewriteRule ^outlet/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ outlet-dett.php?prd=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ prodotti-cat.php?cat=$1&f=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ prodotti-dett.php?cat=$1&prd=$2 [L]
```

If i write in my browser http://www.test.it/outlet/test-2.html i get NOT FOUND...
Why???
Help!!!

Comment: What is the rewritten address of you example? Please clarify what you intend to get from which data. Thks

Comment: RewriteRule ^outlet/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ outlet-dett.php?prd=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

`http://www.test.it/outlet/test-2.html` will be translated to

```
http://www.test.it/outlet-dett.php?prd=test-2
```

Check if that file exists.

Anything after and including the character `?` are called **the query string**, so this is how it goes:

- The server loads `outlet-dett.php`
- and passes it the variable named `prd` with the value `test-2`.
- then the PHP script in `outlet-dett.php` displays the data depending on the value of `prd`.

The `$1` in your rewrite rule is called a **back reference**. It references the match between the first parenthesis in your RegEx.

Comment: @Ste We are talking about the **very same file** here. I edited my answer with the results.

Comment: You either have no file named `outlet-dett.php` in your directory or `http://www.test.it/outlet-dett.php?prd=test-2` should give you an answer. - The third solution is that your PHP sycript replies with 404 (not found), because it has no product called `test-2` in your database.

Comment: I have that file and it work! believe me. if I change htaccess with: RewriteRule ^a/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ outlet-dett.php?prd=$1 [L] it work!!!! why???

Comment: Enable rewrite log with `RewriteLog path/to/logfile` and set level with `RewriteLogLevel 2`. If you don't find your answer you can go higher in the log level.